# Insert... On Duplicate Update - mostly creates duplicates

Tags: mysql

The target table has a primary key and a unique, composite index (Name + UserNo + Title). If I manually add a duplicate I'll get an error. But if I run the stored procedure it merrily adds duplicates as if there was no unique index.

```
CREATE TABLE `tlk_employee_test` (
  `PK_ID` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `UserNo` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Department` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `Branch` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `BranchNo` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `DateTimeStamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Inactivated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `Incentivized` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `Date_Modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_Name_UserNo_Title` (`Name`,`UserNo`,`Title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=209 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO tlk_employee_test(`Name`, UserNo, Department, Branch, BranchNo, Email, Title, Inactivated, Incentivized) 
SELECT t.* FROM
  (
    SELECT s.UserName AS `Name`, s.UserNo, ad.Department, s.Branch, s.BranchNo, ad.Email, ad.Title, s.Inactivated, ad.Incentivized 
    FROM tmp_imported_ad_employees ad INNER JOIN tmp_imported_symitar_employees s ON ad.`Name` = s.UserName 
  ) AS t 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Department = t.Department, Branch = t.Branch, BranchNo = t.BranchNo, Email = t.Email, Inactivated = t.Inactivated;
```

So the Select contains a record like this:
Jeanice Smith, 109, Accounting, Aurora, 4, SmithJ@finsv.org, FSR, 0, 1

A record exists in tlk_employee like this:
Jeanice Smith, 109, Accounting, Aurora, 4, SmithJ@finsv.org, FSR, 0, 1

... and after the stored proc runs, tlk_employee has a duplicate:
Jeanice Smith, 109, Accounting, Aurora, 4, SmithJ@finsv.org, FSR, 0, 1
Jeanice Smith, 109, Accounting, Aurora, 4, SmithJ@finsv.org, FSR, 0, 1

It doesn't seem to matter whether I include the PK_ID or not. Same result. I tried using Values() but same result. I changed the branch number in the temp table for a single record and the tlk_employee record *did* update and no duplicate record was created. I made the same change for the record above and a duplicate record was created except the branch number was what I changed it to but the other record was not updated. ??? Perplexed... Any help is appreciated. This is the fourth day on this problem.

Comment: is it possible they only look like duplicates and have non-printing characters in `Name` or `Department`?

Comment: It's worth investigating. I'll have a look...

Comment: Using my hex editor, characters in both files coming into the temp tables looked okay.

Comment: You might want to check the values in the target table as well (and the temp tables themselves in case something in the "import from files" process is introducing them). If neither of those are the cause, perhaps it is a bug with `INSERT _SELECT_ ON DUPLICATE`; the official documentation gives the impression that MySQL only tangentially supports that form.

Comment: Please don't impose really tight limits on things that don't need them. An email address can easily be 65 characters long, a name is frequently more than 25. Using things like `MEDIUMINT` is usually a sign of overly paranoid schema design. Use `INT` for numbers of all kinds and `VARCHAR(255)` unless you need something longer. It's very rare that shorter restrictions are helpful. Exceptions are very rare but include things like ISO country codes which can be expressed as two characters.

Comment: Uueerdo, you were on to it from the start. There *was* a carriage return lurking in the Title field. Thanks for taking a look at this. I feel like celebrating.

Comment: I don't know how to mark 'Answered'.

Comment: Thanks, tadman, for your input.

Comment: @AlBrandon I'll write up a slightly more formal answer that you can mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-printing characters matter to `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, technically they matter to to the `UNIQUE KEY`(s) that "trigger"/are checked by `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. Such characters once. Such characters can enter your data from many places; they can be imported from poorly formatted (or parsed) source files, through user input not filtered of such characters, or a misbehaving client application.

Some types (and positions) of characters are easier to check/correct than others. Typical "whitespace" characters like tab and newline that are leading and/or trailing can usually be corrected with the `TRIM` MySQL function (and can be detected by comparing it's results to the original field value).

Less common non-printing characters, or characters in the middle of a string, can be more difficult to deal with. Finding them often requires use of regex, and fixing them can often be a semi-manual process. At best involving queries making use of string functions such as `REPLACE()` and `CHAR()`.

It is possible to create a stored procedure, or function, that could loop through and check for each non-printing character separately and fix or return a fixed version of the string; but in my experience, data that needs such fixes often has to be manually handled to fully fix; such as "merging" (or otherwise resolving) references to rows that should have been duplicates, or even being able to actually correct the value when doing so would result in a UNIQUE KEY violation.